# Raphael gradient background for path object doesn't work on IE8 and IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael

I have a following javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var paper = new Raphael(document.getElementById('canvas_container'), 1000, 1000);
    var tetronimo = paper.path("M 700 700 l 0 -50 l -50 0 l 0 -50 l -50 0 l 0 50 l -50 0 l 0 50 z");
    tetronimo.attr({  
        gradient: '90-#526c7a-#64a0c1',
        stroke: '#3b4449',
        'stroke-width': 10,
        'stroke-linejoin': 'round',
        rotation: -90
    });
});
```

HTML is here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Raphael Test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/raphael.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/test.js"></script>
        <link href="css/screen.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="canvas_container"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It works well on many browsers, but gradient background doesn't work on IE7 and IE8. What can be a solution for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out based on [documentation page](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.attr). Instead of using `gradient` property (some old version of library) you need to use `fill` property, and it works!

```
var tetronimo = paper.path("M 700 700 l 0 -50 l -50 0 l 0 -50 l -50 0 l 0 50 l -50 0 l 0 50 z");
tetronimo.attr({  
    fill: '90-#526c7a-#64a0c1',
    'fill-opacity': 0.5,
    stroke: '#3b4449',
    'stroke-width': 10,
    'stroke-linejoin': 'round',
    rotation: -90
});
```